# calling python 3.6 in cmd instead of python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.6

Whenever I try to run python 3.6 in cmd, I only get python 2.7. I need both on my computer. I changed the PATH, I repaired python3.6, I tried moving it etc.

I write "python" in cmd to call it but its always 2.7 even if it is not in the path anymore[image]

Comment: try writing python3 instead of python?

Comment: tried and still not working, says its not recognized as a command

Comment: If you are commonly using different versions of Python, I would highly recommend something like Anaconda. It allows you to create different environments for each version you would like, as well as lets you manage packages between projects.

Comment: `Scripts` is not where `python.exe` is located

Comment: Also, pretty sure the Python 3 installer gives you the option to add it to your PATH automatically

Comment: I checked the case to add to path, and even then it still wasnt showing the right version

Comment: Don't forget on Windows there are two places where PATH is stored, for user and system.  The best was to check is on `cmd.exe` type `path` and inspect it there.

Answer (score 0):

To call python3 from an absolute path, you can use `"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe"`. For example, `"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" hello.py`.